# Removing and Reinstalling Dual Boot Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I had had dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, but I removed Ubuntu partitions from Windows then I restarted and logged in to my Windows account. Then I created a new unallocated partition and made a new usb to boot Ubuntu. In order to reinstall Ubuntu I clicked recovery and then restarted the pc with choosing my bootable usb, but then grun appeared with a black window and when I pressed tab it showed me some commands in which only reboot seemed to me working and I couldn't manage to install Ubuntu. So what should I do to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you sure you chose the live installer on USB drive, not an old ubuntu entry from previous install. If flash drive not seen as boot option, how did you make it. Did you confirm download was correct with md5sum?

Comment: You said you 'clicked recovery', yet you had already deleted Ubuntu's partitions. That makes no sense. What exactly were you 'recovering' from what? Need to see your partitions. Post up output of `sudo parted -l`.

Comment: @oldfred I suspect that an old entry is presented because when I choose it to boot Ubuntu windows boots again.

Comment: @Paul Benson forget about recovery. I just removed Ubuntu partition because it was not enough. Then I created a new one with sufficient disk and created a live usb, but when I tried to boot from it anything happened just windows was booted again.

Comment: If you are at UEFI boot menu, f12, f10 or similar key depending on brand/model system and do not have an entry like UEFI:flash where flash is name or label of flash drive, then flash drive was not created correctly. Try again or use different tool to create flash drive, different port or different flash drive as it may not be correct.

Comment: Yes, my flash's name didn't show in uefi, but I tried different usbs, different ports nothing was changed.